# Need a dynamic Tooltip, which will indicate the percentage of Canvas coloured area in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, canvas, html5-canvas

I have a component which will create a donut chart dynamically. But unable to put a tooltip on the coloured item to show the percentage of the area.

I posting my component. Please help to fix it. Thanks in advance.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import '../../styles/donut.css'


class Donutchart extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            data: {
                numberOfParts: 2,
                parts: { "pt": [40, 60] },//percentage of each parts
                colors: { "cs": ["#5ecd72", "#e74c3c"] }//color of each part
            },
            canvas: ''
        }
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        this.changeState();
        this.updateCanvas();
        this.drawcanvas();
    }

    changeState = () => {
        this.state.canvas = this.refs.canvas.getContext('2d');
    }


    updateCanvas = function (canvasdata) {

        this.set = function (x, y, radius, from, to, lineWidth, strockStyle) {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
            this.radius = radius;
            this.from = from;
            this.to = to;
            this.lineWidth = lineWidth;
            this.strockStyle = strockStyle;
        }
        this.draw = function (data) {
            canvasdata.beginPath();
            canvasdata.lineWidth = this.lineWidth;
            canvasdata.strokeStyle = this.strockStyle;
            canvasdata.arc(this.x, this.y, this.radius, this.from, this.to);
            canvasdata.stroke();
            var numberOfParts = data.numberOfParts;
            var parts = data.parts.pt;
            var colors = data.colors.cs;
            var df = 0;
            for (var i = 0; i < numberOfParts; i++) {
                canvasdata.beginPath();
                canvasdata.strokeStyle = colors[i];
                canvasdata.arc(this.x, this.y, this.radius, df, df + (Math.PI * 2) * (parts[i] / 100));
                canvasdata.stroke();
                df += (Math.PI * 2) * (parts[i] / 100);
            }
        }
    }

    drawcanvas = () => {
        let drawDount = new this.updateCanvas(this.state.canvas);
        drawDount.set(100, 65, 50, 0, Math.PI * 2, 25, "#fff");
        drawDount.draw(this.state.data);
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div className='box-container'>
                <h4 className='header-head'>HDL</h4>
                <canvas ref="canvas" id="chart" width={200} height={140} />
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Donutchart;
```

Now I have hard coded all values. But later on I will receive data by props.

[Now the output is looking like this. I need a Tooltip on hover of coloured item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oNUQr.png)